# Visual studio Task Runner Explorer doesn't recognize gulp tasks

Tags: visual-studio, gulp, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0, task-runner-explorer

In visual studio 2017, in an attempt to add `SASS` compilation using Gulp to a `netcore2` project using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/less-sass-fa#sass) tutorial I ran into trouble with the Task Runner Explorer. On the project I want to add gulp to, the Task Runner does not display **any** task.

[image]

If I try to add a `Gulpfile.js` to an other netcore 2 project, that it be older or newly created, I can see some tasks from the `bundleconfig.json` and an empty task list for the `Gulpfile.js`.
[image]

On all of these projects I have an identical `gulpfile.js` which is as follow:

```
/*
This file is the main entry point for defining Gulp tasks and using Gulp plugins.
Click here to learn more. https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=518007
*/
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/",
    sass: "./wwwroot/scss/",
    css: "./wwwroot/css/"
};

gulp.task('scss', function ()
{
    return gulp.src(paths.sass + '/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.webroot + 'css/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function ()
{
    gulp.watch(paths.sass + '**/*.scss', ["scss"]);
});
```

I can run the gulp jobs using the PowerShell command line and they properly compile my `scss`, which means the `gulpfile.js` is valid.

As per other Stack Overflow questions/answers I tried:

- installing Gulp both locally and globally, no change [src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41470776/6838730) [src2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43258738/6838730).
- adding an external tool that targets `nodejs` [src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31444245/6838730) [image: external tools]
- adding  the `npm task runner` VS2017 extension
- adding  the `Bundler & Minifier` VS2017 extension
- restarting VS2017 a few dozens of time in total, mostly in between each of the above steps/attempts
- running `npm install` several times
- taking the project out of the solution folder in which it was [src](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29070618/6838730)

Regarding the lines without a `src` I could not find the thread that said to try this particular fix, but I did try it.

None of the above fixed it. Has anyone run into this problem and fixed it in an other way than the ones described above ? Does anyone know why this happens and what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. 
I do not know exactly which step fixed my problem but I did it all in this order:

1. Remove gulp both locally and globally
2. Remove the `Bundler & Minifier` vs extension
3. Remove the `npm task runner` vs extension
4. Restart VS 2017 (make sure it takes into account the removal of the extensions
5. Create a new netcore 2.0 app at the root of the solution with an unique name (several of my projects had the same name, in different folders)
6. Copy/paste all the files from the old project to the new one
7. Restart VS 2017
8. Right click on `bundleconfig.json` --> `Bundler & minifier` --> `Convert to Gulp`. This will install gulp and generate a `gulpfile.js` at the root of the project.
9. Add the needed Gulp tasks
10. Right click on the `gulpfile.js` --> `Task runner explorer`
11. ***DONE***

Comment: Thanks, @Mathieu! A 3-step version of this worked for me, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67161401/177710

Answer (score 4):

For me the fix was running the Gulp locally.

I tried running it globally but it didn't work.

Comment: it worked... installing gulp locally did the trick...

Comment: Still a solution with Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by @mathieu-viales](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47509444/177710) inspired me to do the following **which also worked**:

1. **Remove** the affected **project** from the solution, save and close.
2. Reopen the solution, **re-add** the **project** to the solution.
3. **Done**! The Gulp tasks now appeared in the VS Test Runner explorer.